# What should I do so that the default text is not selected and should disappear when I click inside combo(ExtJs3.2)?

Tags: extjs, xtype

Below is ExtJs3.2 code for a combo box with a default text.When I click on the combo box, the default text does not disappear and infact gets selected. You can also search names in combo by entering initials of the name. What should I do so that the default text is not selected and should disappear when I click inside combo.

```
{
                                            xtype: 'combo',
                                            displayField: 'name',
                                            emptyText:'Select Route'+"*",
                                            id: 'road-edit-form-roadList',
                                            allowBlank: false,
                                            forceSelection :true,
                                            typeAhead: true,
                                            triggerAction: 'all',
                                            mode: 'local',
                                            valueField:'id',
                                            store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                                                   //url: 'getRoadList',
                                                   url: 'ajax-route/ajax.jsp?action=getRoadList',
                                                   fields: ['id','name']
                                            }),
                                            listeners:{
                                                   'beforequery': function(qe){
                                                          qe.combo.getStore().load({
                                                                 params:{
                                                                       query:qe.query
                                                                 }
                                                          });
                                                   }
                                            }
                                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
focus : function (thisCmp, eventObj, eventOptions) {
            thisCmp.inputEl.dom.placeholder = ''; //force the removal of the placeholding text
        }
```

More ref : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?230850-combo-with-watermark-problem